# Get chat_id from bot to bot conversation

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

So What Im trying to accomplish is a bot that forwards messages from one specific user to one specific group chat. I started my testing by using my own chat_id and the bot perfectly forwards my messages to the right groupchat.

The problem is tho, that I want to forward messages that I receive *from a bot*. So I am trying to gather the chat_id between this bot and my bot but I can't get my head around how I should send and/or receive a message from this bot to gather said chat_id because I cant use it's @username in a /sendMessage? URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?**
>  Bots talking to each
>   other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this,
>   we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots
>   regardless of mode.

[Telegram Bots FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I guess I missed it when reading the FAQ earlier. So as a follow-up question: is it possible to create a system that forwards the messages *I* receive or perhaps a system that automatically forwards the messages *I* receive to my bot